# if statement to slide between data sets d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to "slide" between datasets in d3.js. I have It working so That I can slide from the original set to the next using:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, "data/results_data.csv")
  .defer(d3.csv, "data/results_data_09.csv")
  .defer(d3.json, "data/world_geo.json")
  .await(function(error, d2010, d2009, j_data) {
      results_data['2009'] = d2009;
      results_data['2010'] = d2010;
      json_data = j_data;
      drawVis('2010');
      });
```

and:

```
var slider = d3.select('#year');
slider.on('change', function() {
 //IF STATEMENT TO GO HERE
    grabber =[];
    drawVis('2009');
});
```

However I want to be able to slide back and forth using an if statement. The problem being I can't figure out how to do it.

I have this form that I use for the slider:

```
<form>
    <label for="year">Please select a year: </label>
    <label for="year">Please select a year: </label>
    <input type="range" min=2009 max=2010 step=1 id="year" value=2010 oninput="selected_year.value = year.value">
    <output name="selected_year" id="selected_year">2010</output>
</form>
```

Is there a way of taking the id of selected year and using that in the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UPDATE* 
I have managed to figure it out myself for anyone interested:

I created this variable

```
    var selectedYear = document.getElementById("selected_year");
```

Then this if statement within my function:

```
if(selectedYear.value = 2009) {
    grabber =[];
    drawVis('2009');
}
```

and it all works now!